# Giving rocket propellants an opposite charge for perfect mixing?

Tags: fuel, design-alternative, fuel-system

One of the challenges in achieving theoretical efficiency is the mixing of both an oxidiser and fuel. This means separating both propellants from each other whilst pairing them with their counterpart. If the fuel was given one charge, and the oxidiser another, then similarly charged propellants would repel each other, but still be attracted to the other fuel/oxidiser, achieving perfect mixing. Are there any fuels with this capacity, and if not What additives could be used to increase its conductivity? Is LOX's weak magnetic charge large enough to impact the mixing process? Could this increase efficiency or decrease injector complexity, mass or propellant pressure loss?

Comment: Yhe repulsion inside the tanks would create trouble. Also, more insulation would be needed to prevent discharge. Maybe we could have a generator charge the fuel as it is fed?

Comment: @Abdullah Perhaps the charge can be imparted to the propellant on its way from the tank to the chamber. The liquid in the tank would be neutral.